# Conditional formatting using "IF" condition in VBA is not working?

Tags: excel, vba

The code runs without any error but the conditional formatting is not working.Also can we offset the cell using Address.Eg `cf = blue.Address(orow / 2 - 1, -ocol / 2)`.

```
blue.Select
                    With Selection
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                        cf = blue.Address(orow / 2 - 1, -ocol / 2)
                         cf1 = blue.Address(orow / 2 - 1, ocol / 2)
                         cf2 = blue.Address(-orow / 2 - 1, -ocol / 2)
                         cf3 = blue.Address(-orow / 2 - 1, ocol / 2)

                        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=_
                    "=OR(LEN(cf.address)=0, LEN(cf1.address)=0,LEN(cf2.address)=0,LEN(cf3.address)=0)"
                    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
                        .TintAndShade = 0.8
                    End With
                    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the code posted and difficult to evaluate all of it. But try replacing:

```
"=OR(LEN(cf.address)=0, LEN(cf1.address)=0,LEN(cf2.address)=0,LEN(cf3.address)=0)"
```

with

```
"=OR(LEN(" & cf.address & ")=0, LEN(" & cf.address & ")=0,LEN(" & cf.address & ")=0,LEN(" & cf.address & ")=0)"
```

Otherwise, VBA considers everything as string, not caring about your variables...

Comment: Your code did work but is there a way to do conditional formatting(using VBA) without using address/string(ie by just using ranges).

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: I'm afraid, not... But you can use Named ranges.